# Subfields of Galois Extensions and association with Galois Groups

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, primitive-roots, galois-extensions

Let $\mathbb{K}\subseteq \mathbb{L}$ be a Galois extension with order $n$. If $p$  is a prime divisor of $n$, show that exists a subfield $\mathbb{M}$ of $\mathbb{L}$ such that $[\mathbb{L},\mathbb{M}]=p$.

My try:

Since $\mathbb{L}$ is Galois, $o(Gal(\mathbb{K},\mathbb{L}))=n$ and by Cauchy Theorem, there is a group $H \subseteq Gal(\mathbb{K},\mathbb{L})$ with such order.

If I prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $Gal(\mathbb{K},\mathbb{L})$, then the Theorem of Galois correspondence give me subfield of $\mathbb{L}$ with the desired order, and by the tower law i can prove that if $n=pq$, then $[\mathbb{M},\mathbb{K}]=q$.

My doubt is how to ensure the normality of $H$ to conclude my proof?

An aplication of this exercise is to the the unique existence subfields $\mathbb{K}_{1}, \mathbb{K}_{2}$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that  $[\mathbb{\mathbb{K}_{1}},\mathbb{Q}]=2$ and $[\mathbb{\mathbb{K}_{1}},\mathbb{Q}]=3$.

I would like to understand the first problem to solve and understand the second.

Comment: You don't need normality of $H$ unless you want $\Bbb M$ to be Galois over $\Bbb K$. That's not something you're asked for.

Comment: The title is not good. Subfields of groups?

Comment: Sorry, I confuse the order of "Groups "and "extension", I edited.

Comment: @Arthur, so, I can conclude the exercise with my idea above and the use it to prove the aplication i mentioned?